# How do I find $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}{\sin^2x \over e^{-1/x}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+}{\sin^2x \over e^{-1/x}}
$$

Have tried to apply the L'Hospital's rule, but the denominator stays always the same $\left( {d \over dx}e^x=e^x \right)$ and brings $-\infty$.

What else can be done if this powerful rule ships no help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change variable: as $x\rightarrow0^+$, then $-\frac1x\rightarrow-\infty.$ Hence
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\sin^2x}{e^{-\frac1x}}\stackrel{-\frac1x=t}{=}\lim_{t\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{\sin^2(-1/t)}{e^t}
$$

Observe now that $\sin^2(-1/t)\sim_{t\rightarrow-\infty}1/t^2$ thus
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{\sin^2(-1/t)}{e^t}=
\lim_{t\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{1}{t^2e^t}=+\infty
$$
since $t^2e^t\rightarrow0^+$ as $t\rightarrow-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Using some Taylor polynomials

$$\sin^2x\cdot e^{1/x}=\sin^2x\left(1+\frac1x+\frac1{2x^2}+\frac1{3!x^3}+\ldots\right)\xrightarrow[x\to 0^+]{}\infty$$

since

$$\frac{\sin^x}{x^n}=\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^2\frac1{x^{n-2}}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}\infty\;\;\;\text{for}\;\;n>2$$

Comment: btw Congrats @DonAntonio for reaching +100k !! $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$

Comment: Yeah I agree! Congrats DonAntonio!!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful that :

$\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$ but $\frac{d}{dx}e^{f(x)}\neq e^{f(x)}$

This should help you if you really understand what i have written...

Seeing $\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}= ??$ would be of some help to you...

Comment: I know that ${d \over dx}e^{f(x)}=f^\prime(x)\cdot e^{f(x)}$

Comment: So, where did you used it???

Comment: I derived numerator and denominator using L'Hospital's rule, which led me to $$\lim_{x \to 0+}{\sin2x \cdot x^2 \over e^{-1/x}}$$. I can apply it again but it won't help me to get rid of $e^{-1/x}$ in denominator.

Comment: I was trying to say (vaguely) what حكيم الفيلسوف الضائع has said in his comment.... do you understand what he said..